# Starting the plot at the origin, showing missing ticks, and pushing arrow head a little further

Tags: plotting

I have the following data:

```
datacon0 = {936.1, 1203.4, 1397};
datacon3 = {733.7, 1076.9, 1202.3};
datacon6 = {788.7, 1170.4, 1298};
datacon9 = {761.2, 1142.9, 1273.8};
datacon15 = {1302.4, 1195.7, 869};
datacon18 = {1342, 1183.6, 961.4};
datacon21 = {1369.5, 1232, 1025.2};
datacon24 = {1310.1, 1192.4, 1015.3};
```

and the following plot:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, Around[Mean[datacon0], StandardDeviation[datacon0]]}, {3, Around[Mean[datacon3], StandardDeviation[datacon3]]}, {6, Around[Mean[datacon6], StandardDeviation[datacon6]]}, {9, Around[Mean[datacon9], StandardDeviation[datacon9]]}, {15, Around[Mean[datacon15], StandardDeviation[datacon15]]}, {18, Around[Mean[datacon18], StandardDeviation[datacon18]]}, {21, Around[Mean[datacon21], StandardDeviation[datacon21]]}, {24, Around[Mean[datacon24], StandardDeviation[datacon24]]}}, Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"}, AxesLabel -> {0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.045}}], ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> Large, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, LabelStyle -> {15, GrayLevel[0]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

This plot has several problems and I appreciate any help:

1. I need the plot to start from (0,0) and these zeros to be shown with out extra lines on the left and bottom.
2. On the x-axis, strangely enough, number 24 is not shown.
3. The first bar has gone through the arrow head, and I need to push the arrow head a little further.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xvals = {0, 3, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24};

datacons = Symbol["datacon" <> ToString @ #] & /@ xvals;

toAround = MapApply[Around] @* Map[Through @* {Mean, StandardDeviation}];

data = Transpose@{xvals, toAround @ datacons};


ListLinePlot[data,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, Scaled[.1]}, {0, Scaled[.1]}},
 BaseStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[3],
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[15],
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
 Ticks -> {xvals, Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"},
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium],
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math", 15, GrayLevel[0]},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: @Shakeri, please see the update.

Comment: Try replacing  `"cm"` with  `cm^2` ( or with `ToString[cm^2, StandardForm]`).

Comment: use `"Number of microbes (\[CapitalOmega] \[Times] " <> 
 ToString[cm^2, StandardForm] <> ")"` or `"Number of microbes\n (\[CapitalOmega] \[Times] " <> 
 ToString[cm^2, StandardForm] <> ")"`

Comment: You can also use `Row[{"Number of microbes (\[CapitalOmega] \[Times] ", cm^2, ")"}]`

Comment: @Shakeri, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: just a more streamlined version of the original.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 
   Around[Mean[datacon0], StandardDeviation[datacon0]]}, {3, 
   Around[Mean[datacon3], StandardDeviation[datacon3]]}, {6, 
   Around[Mean[datacon6], StandardDeviation[datacon6]]}, {9, 
   Around[Mean[datacon9], StandardDeviation[datacon9]]}, {15, 
   Around[Mean[datacon15], StandardDeviation[datacon15]]}, {18, 
   Around[Mean[datacon18], StandardDeviation[datacon18]]}, {21, 
   Around[Mean[datacon21], StandardDeviation[datacon21]]}, {24, 
   Around[Mean[datacon24], StandardDeviation[datacon24]]}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.045}}], 
 ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> Large, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {15, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0, 28}, {700, 1500}}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To answer your questions:

```
ListLinePlot[{{0, 
   Around[Mean[datacon0], StandardDeviation[datacon0]]}, {3, 
   Around[Mean[datacon3], StandardDeviation[datacon3]]}, {6, 
   Around[Mean[datacon6], StandardDeviation[datacon6]]}, {9, 
   Around[Mean[datacon9], StandardDeviation[datacon9]]}, {15, 
   Around[Mean[datacon15], StandardDeviation[datacon15]]}, {18, 
   Around[Mean[datacon18], StandardDeviation[datacon18]]}, {21, 
   Around[Mean[datacon21], StandardDeviation[datacon21]]}, {24, 
   Around[Mean[datacon24], StandardDeviation[datacon24]]}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 3, 6, 9, 15, 18, 21, 24}, Automatic}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (h)", "cm"}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{{0.045}}], 
 ImagePadding -> 80, ImageSize -> Large, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Math"}, 
 LabelStyle -> {15, GrayLevel[0]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0, 28}, {700, 1500}}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[{{0, Mean[datacon0]}, {3, Mean[datacon3]}, {6, 
      Mean[datacon6]}, {9, Mean[datacon9]}, {15, 
      Mean[datacon15]}, {18, Mean[datacon18]}, {21, 
      Mean[datacon21]}, {24, Mean[datacon24]}}], Darker[Blue], 
   Thickness[0.005], 
   Line[{{0.1, Mean[datacon0] - StandardDeviation[datacon0]}, {0, 
      Mean[datacon0] + StandardDeviation[datacon0]}}]}]
```

[image]